# Bootstrap pagination is not working in Admin LTE template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

I'm using AdminLTE for one of my projects.There's a pagination area whens showing results.I used bootstrap pagination class .pagination to show the pagination.But it's not working.Then i got a sample html block from AdminLTE which uses pagination itself.That class is .pagination pagination-sm inline. It's also not working.So i'm confused about this.Following are my code blocks which i used.

AdminLTE css class

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm inline">
<li><button>1</button></li>
<li><button>2</button></li>
<li><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Bootstrap css class

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li><button>1</button></li>
<li><button>2</button></li>
<li><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could able to solve this.This template not detects button for the pagination.Once change it to a anchor tag, it's applying  bootstrap pagination.Code as below.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm inline">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```